# Adding feature class and applying symbology in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, layer-file

Using an ArcPy script run from a toolbox, I want to import a feature class from a geodatabase into an ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2 map and then symbolise that layer based on a lyrx file stored on disk.

Here is a simplified version:

```
import arcpy, os
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = aprx.listMaps('*')[0]
outputWorkspace = r"C:\Path\To\MyProject.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = outputWorkspace
out_fc = "fc_data"
out_fc_p = os.path.join(outputWorkspace, out_fc)
ref_lyrx = r"C:\Path\To\symbol_ref.lyrx"
m.addDataFromPath(out_fc_p)
out_fc_lyr = m.listLayers()[0]
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(out_fc_lyr, ref_lyrx)
```

The script completes without error but no visible change is made to the symbology.

Is this a bug?

I've reviewed many similar questions but have been unable to resolve this.

I tried also first converting the fc to a layer using `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management().getOutput()` before adding to the map with `m.addLayer()` and then using `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management()` but get exactly the same outcome.

Comment: What happens if you hit refresh?

Comment: Yep, manually refreshing doesn't change anything. Also, it seems that the RefreshActiveView function from ArcMap has not been implemented in Pro so I can't implement it in the script.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding a layer to your map and running just the `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer()` from the command line?  Does that work?

Comment: Yes, same result - the line runs (no error) but symbology still not updated, which leads me to think it may be a bug?...

Comment: How precisely did you turn the code snippet that you have presented into "an ArcPy script run from a toolbox"?  As a test, have you tried giving a path to your `*.aprx` when you create the ArcGISProject object, and then saving `aprx` at the end to see whether the rest of your code works that way?

Comment: I edited the code to include the full path to the aprx and then save it at the end as you suggested, but now the layer to be symbolised won't even be added to the map despite the script running and completing successfully.

Answer (score -1):

yes, that looks like a bug. Had the exact same issue
https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDEyMDkwNg==

Comment: The bug you've linked to is to do with ModelBuilder and there's no suggestion in the question that ModelBuilder is part of the workflow.